# How does the 'static' keyword work in Java?

Tags: java

how does the static keyword vary to not using it with a method, could you give me an example where the result is different because the word is used and not used, thanks. Andy.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: This is a very basic Java Question, and not Android related. The question shows very little research effort. -1

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/howtoaccessstaticmethod.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static method can be called on the class, like this:

```
SomeClass.method();
```

A non-static method can only be called on an instance of that class, like this:

```
SomeClass object = new SomeClass();
object.method();
```

In a static method, you only have access to other static methods and members. So, to use the this keyword in a method, it must not be declared static. Static methods give functionality to the class itself, while non-static methods give functionality to an object of that class.

Comment: cheers ;p most people explain this stuff so complicated

Answer (score 1):

When you create a standalone program you have the following method as starting point.

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
```

Now just remove the static word and try to run the program. It will complain that main method not found.

To start execution, JVM needs a main method which it should be able to access *without creating an instance of the enclosing class*.

Bottom line is : a `static` type of entity (class, method, variable etc) exists without any instance being created. They can be directly accessed with the notation `Myclass.myInt` or `MyClass.myMethod()`  So they exists on **per class definition**  and are **common for all the class instances**.

Answer (score 0):

The result  will not be different.

If the method uses only other static things, then it will return the same result, whether it has been declared static or not.

If the method uses non-static things, you cannot make it static (it will be a compile error).

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can't use any `instance` variables. The `this` keyword can't be used in a static methods. 
A static method can be accessed *without creating an instance of the class*. If you try to use a non-static method and variable defined in this class then the compiler will say that non-static variable or method cannot be referenced from a static context. Static method can call *only other static methods and  static variables* defined in the class.